# Maven internal.aether and eclipse aether-util dependency issue

Tags: java, maven

I am getting below exception while starting the application. I am not sure where exactly is the problem. I tried excluding them from maven-core, but still getting same exception. Any help/suggestion would be appreciable.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.apache.maven.internal.aether.DefaultRepositorySystemSessionFactory.newRepositorySession(DefaultRepositorySystemSessionFactory.java:180)

The following method did not exist:

    org.eclipse.aether.util.repository.DefaultMirrorSelector.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/eclipse/aether/util/repository/DefaultMirrorSelector;

The calling method's class, org.apache.maven.internal.aether.DefaultRepositorySystemSessionFactory, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-core/3.8.1/maven-core-3.8.1.jar!/org/apache/maven/internal/aether/DefaultRepositorySystemSessionFactory.class

The called method's class, org.eclipse.aether.util.repository.DefaultMirrorSelector, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.1.0.redhat-1/aether-util-1.1.0.redhat-1.jar!/org/eclipse/aether/util/repository/DefaultMirrorSelector.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.eclipse.aether.util.repository.DefaultMirrorSelector: file:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.1.0.redhat-1/aether-util-1.1.0.redhat-1.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.apache.maven.internal.aether.DefaultRepositorySystemSessionFactory and org.eclipse.aether.util.repository.DefaultMirrorSelector
```

Comment: What kind of application do you create where you need those dependencies? Do you write a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library, but this may be a dependency version incompatibility issue (whether or not the call is made from another library).
From what I see in your post, you make the following call:

```
org.eclipse.aether.util.repository.DefaultMirrorSelector.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/eclipse/aether/util/repository/DefaultMirrorSelector;
```

From the docs version 1.9.0, I see the following api:

[image]

https://maven.apache.org/resolver/apidocs/org/eclipse/aether/util/repository/DefaultMirrorSelector.html

Hope it helps.